# Why "вести" but "веду"

Tags: глаголы, орфография, спряжение

Let's compare three verbs and their first person singular forms:

- нести - несу
- везти - везу
- вести - ве**д**у

Is there a particular reason why, in вести, the с turned into д ? Is there any intuitive reason (for ex. spelling rules) why this would happen, or would it be considered an irregular verb?

Thanks.

Comment: I think that in this case д somehow turned into "с" since every conjugation form of вести except infinitive has д.

Comment: In a grad school class I asked the professor why, given these changes, we say идти instead of *исти. He shrugged and said it was basically the exception that proves the rule... that sometimes the most common words are the most conservative & resistant to change.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not irregular but all you can do is just to memoize such cases.

While the `ст` -> `т` happens in some verbs like "плести"/ "плету", "цвести"/"цвету", "мести"/"мету" for instance, a change to `д` is not that rare as well, check out for instance:

- блюсти / блюду
- брести / бреду
- красть / краду
- прясть / пряду

So it's not something exotic. Here's a small explanation I borrowed from [this](https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=de&tl=en&text=der%20Infinitiv%20l%C3%A4%C3%9Ft%20das%20nicht%20erkennen%2C%20da%20nach%20SLavischen%20Lautgesetzen%20%D0%B4%2C%20%D1%82%20vor%20%22%D1%82%22%20zu%20c%20wurden) book:
[image]

"Der Infinitiv läßt das nicht erkennen, da nach slavischen Lautgesetzen д, т vor "т" zu c wurden"

Or, in my free translation - the infinitive doesn't indicate this because, due to Slavic sound law `д` and `т` before `т` became `c`, so "вести" was initially "ведти" and what you've found are the traces of that old spelling.

This is, by the way, the case in all examples mentioned above. If you take a closer look you'll see that 'красть' was derived [from](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C) "*kro-d-" stem, ["блюсти](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B1%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8)" can be traced to Proto-Indo-European *bʰewdʰ-, ["брести"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8) is from " *bʰredʰ-." and "прясть" we [got from](http://www.endic.ru/rusethy/Prjast-3426.html) "*prędti".

The scientific term for this changes is "the assibilation of dental stops". The last thing I want to add that this happens very likely in Pre-Slavic since Slavic languages share such similarities with Baltic languages.

Comment: An excellent answer! Thank you!

Comment: No, the insertion of -s- between d and t is much more ancient, coming from mid-PIE.

Comment: @Anixx this is exactly what I meant by Pre-Slavic but you term is more precise, also - nice answer! See no contradiction between our answers whatsoever.

Answer (score 4):

This is because of the rule already in Proto-Indo-European: if a word had a root ending in -d- or -dh- and a suffix starting with -t-, then an -s- sound would be inserted in between.

For instance, the PIE had roots e̯es- "to be" and "e̯ed-" "to eat", they had forms ***e̯edsti*** "eats" and ***e̯esti*** "is", which both gave the coinciding Russian form ***есть***.

Similarly, ***везти*** comes from u̯eĝh- "convey", with -ĝh- after Slavic sound changes becoming -з- and appearing in all forms with this root while ***вести*** comes from PIE u̯edh- which when combined with suffix starting with -t- would have -s- inserted, but not in other cases.

In other words, if there was no fusion, it would be ведсти, not вести.